# Unable to locate  com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot in web start

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, java-web-start, jar-signing

I am new to java web start.
I am trying to lunch one-jar using web start.but i am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate
>   com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot in the java.class.path: consider using
>   -Done-jar.jar.path to specify the one-jar filename.   at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.getMyJarPath(Boot.java:400)   at
>   com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:212)     at
>   com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

my jnlp file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>my application</title>
        <vendor>example</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.5+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="My_Application.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot">
  </application-desc>
   <update check="background"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar problem and came across your question. It appears One-Jar does not support JWS, see [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/one-jar/forums/forum/380843/topic/1788843) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292837/does-jws-support-to-launch-one-jar).